# IP packet generate manually?

Tags: network-scanners, ip-spoofing, packet

I have heard that we can create ip-packets by our own and send it to a network or a  host.
How this Can Be Done ?Please Explain step by step??

Comment: Off topic, but have a look at hping or scapy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PCap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) library can be used not only to sniff packets, but also to construct and send packets.

> In the field of computer network administration, pcap (packet capture)
>   consists of an application programming interface (API) for capturing
>   network traffic. Unix-like systems implement pcap in the libpcap
>   library; Windows uses a port of libpcap known as WinPcap.

There is a good [example](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut8.html):

> The simplest way to send a packet is shown in the following code
>   snippet. After opening an adapter, pcap_sendpacket() is called to send
>   a hand-crafted packet. pcap_sendpacket() takes as arguments a buffer
>   containing the data to send, the length of the buffer and the adapter
>   that will send it. Notice that the buffer is sent to the net as is,
>   without any manipulation. This means that the application has to
>   create the correct protocol headers in order to send something
>   meaningful.

Please note you have the full control. You can change Ethernet frame as well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pcap.h>


void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
pcap_t *fp;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
u_char packet[100];
int i;

    /* Check the validity of the command line */
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s interface (e.g. 'rpcap://eth0')", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    /* Open the output device */
    if ( (fp= pcap_open(argv[1],            // name of the device
                        100,                // portion of the packet to capture (only the first 100 bytes)
                        PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS,  // promiscuous mode
                        1000,               // read timeout
                        NULL,               // authentication on the remote machine
                        errbuf              // error buffer
                        ) ) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nUnable to open the adapter. %s is not supported by WinPcap\n", argv[1]);
        return;
    }

    /* Supposing to be on ethernet, set mac destination to 1:1:1:1:1:1 */
    packet[0]=1;
    packet[1]=1;
    packet[2]=1;
    packet[3]=1;
    packet[4]=1;
    packet[5]=1;

    /* set mac source to 2:2:2:2:2:2 */
    packet[6]=2;
    packet[7]=2;
    packet[8]=2;
    packet[9]=2;
    packet[10]=2;
    packet[11]=2;

    /* Fill the rest of the packet */
    for(i=12;i<100;i++)
    {
        packet[i]=i%256;
    }

    /* Send down the packet */
    if (pcap_sendpacket(fp, packet, 100 /* size */) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nError sending the packet: \n", pcap_geterr(fp));
        return;
    }

    return;
}
```

**Update**

There are several wrappers available:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpcap/
- http://jnetpcap.com/
- https://code.google.com/p/sjpcap/

Comment: Can You Give the above code in Java and package list  that support pcap?

Comment: See update. This question is for stackoverflow.